# Can a bank have deposits at another bank?

Tags: banking, reserve-requirement-ratio

Can a bank create an account at another bank and get a loan in the form of deposits at that bank? If so, could these deposits at the other bank be used to satisfy the first bank's reserve/liquidity requirements? Or do only deposits in the central bank (fed) count toward reserve/liquidity requirements?